# Material UI - TypeError: (0 , _capitalize.default) is not a function

Tags: jestjs, material-ui, enzyme, react-intl

On running jest tests locally, test suite fails when trying to mount the component with a ThemeProvider.

Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the issue on a repo.
I tried to reproduce the same behaviour in the sandbox but the behaviour doesn't reproduce.
See example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-nightingale-e7gg2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I'm using react-inl and @mui and in the test environment it just fails to compile. Complains about `_capitalize.default` not being a function, however I checked node_modules and the function is clearly there exported. Tried to re-install the packages as well just to make sure files are not corrupt.

It seems the error is happening when trying to ***mount*** the element in the virtual dom to run some unit tests. Snapshot testing with shallow rendering works just fine.

**Dump of the error**

```
TypeError: (0 , _capitalize.default) is not a function
    at InputBase (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/@material-ui/core/InputBase/InputBase.js:453:96)
    at renderWithHooks (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15108:18)
    at updateForwardRef (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16746:20)
    at beginWork$1 (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18522:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:347:14)
    at invokeEventListeners (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:193:27)
    at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:119:9)
    at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:82:17)
    at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLElement-impl.js:30:27)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:157:21)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:397:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:454:31)
    at beginWork$$1 (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23217:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22211:12)
    at workLoopSync (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22185:22)
    at renderRoot (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21878:11)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21419:22)
    at scheduleRootUpdate (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24319:3)
    at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24347:10)
    at updateContainer (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24436:10)
    at /home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24963:7
    at unbatchedUpdates (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21687:12)
    at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:24962:5)
    at Object.render (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:25042:12)
    at fn (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:437:26)
    at /home/circleci/project/node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:354:37
    at batchedUpdates$1 (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21643:12)
    at act (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:1002:14)
    at Object.act (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:1418:12)
    at wrapAct (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:354:13)
    at Object.render (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/src/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:423:16)
    at new ReactWrapper (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/enzyme/src/ReactWrapper.js:115:16)
    at mount (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/enzyme/src/mount.js:10:10)
    at mountWithIntl (/home/circleci/project/test/intlHelper.js:22:10)
    at Suite.<anonymous> (/home/circleci/project/src/app/components/statisticsFilter.test.js:52:23)
    at addSpecsToSuite (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:339:25)
    at Env.describe (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:308:7)
    at describe (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/jasmine_light.js:99:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/circleci/project/src/app/components/statisticsFilter.test.js:26:1)
    at Runtime._execModule (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:694:13)
    at Runtime.requireModule (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:376:14)
    at /home/circleci/project/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js:129:13
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js:170:30)
    at /home/circleci/project/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js:189:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /home/circleci/project/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js:167:12
    at jasmine2 (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js:138:17)
    at /home/circleci/project/node_modules/jest-runner/build/run_test.js:187:24
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/jest-runner/build/run_test.js:315:30)
    at /home/circleci/project/node_modules/jest-runner/build/run_test.js:326:15
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

### Context

Trying to run the tests locally and it just breaks when trying to mount things.

### Your Environment

React: 16.9.0
Flow: 0.2.2.3
Flow-typed: 2.5.1
Material UI  Core: 4.11.0
Material UI Icons: 4.9.1
Material UI Pickers: 3.2.10
Material UI Lab: 4.0.0-alpha.56